# SQL request gets me error "AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" while targetting neko

Tags: mysql, haxe

I'm trying make a basic SQL query with this `main` function :

```
var cnx = Mysql.connect({ 
        host : "localhost",
        port : 3306,
        user : "root",
        pass : "",
        socket : null,
        database : "db"
    });
    var rset = cnx.request("SELECT * FROM stadium");
```

But when I try to build it, targetting neko, I get the error `AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed` and my program exits.

The second instruction since to be responsible for it, since commenting it leaves the program running without error.

Any clue on what might cause this and how to fix it ?

**EDIT:** Ok, so the error might not be the cause of the crash, but rather caused by it. The question is more "Why does a SQL request make my app crash, with no error displayed ?".

Comment: Well, the error message is not unique to your code. It is caused by OpenAL, an audio library used by some a Haxe library's crashes with the rest of your application. I don't use any of that MySQL stuff, so I don't know why it is crashing in the first place. Sorry I couldn't be of further help